# How many objects can I perceive to all be travelling at speed arbitrarily close to $\sqrt 2\cdot c$ relative to each other?

Tags: classical-mechanics, quantum-mechanics, special-relativity

Classically, space is a $\Bbb R^3$ manifold.  According to relativity, spacetime is $4$d although I understand this is Minkowski space.  The thing I was curious about, is whether the two theories agree or disagree on how many orthogonal geodesics are possible.  This is the precise formulation of the question I derived which captures its essence, in both the Newtonian and Relativistic models:

> From the point of view of my own reference frame, how many objects can I perceive to all be travelling at speed arbitrarily close to $\sqrt 2\cdot c$ relative to each other?  Do Quantum theory, Newtonian physics and relativity agree?

This question was received very badly on Physics stack Exchange.  I'm neurodivergent so I can accept that it's me, but I don't think it's a bad question - but I do apologise in advance if you don't like it.  It's a maths and physics question so I thought I'd try my luck here - from a pure mathematical perspective, so I accept I can't expect an empirical answer here.

EDIT

Where I give $\sqrt2 \cdot c$ as the apparent speed from the point of view of an observer, I'l using the interpretation of superluminar speed referred to in this answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/107359/122325

Comment: None, because the square root of two is greater than one.

Comment: @JohnDouma From my reference frame I can perceive two objects to be moving at up to $2c$ relative to each other. Consider for example a photon approaching me from the North and another approaching from the South.

Comment: @JohnDouma nothing travels faster than light but if you're traveling towards something at  $\frac34 c$ and it's coming towards you at  $\frac34 c$ it will appear superluminal as it approaches and subliminal as it recedes.

Comment: I voted to close because it contains multiple questions and it's unclear what you're asking. An example of what you mean would likely add clarity. It's also not clear to me that this is a mathematics problem.

Comment: I think you fellas need to crack a book on special relativity. You're telling those in the know that the moon is made of green cheese. I can only imagine the reaction on the physics site. @CyclotomicField No, you won't perceive it as faster than light.

Comment: @JohnDouma from my reference frame can I perceive two photons to be at light speed and opposing directions to each other, and does that look to me like they're travelling at $2c$ relative to each other? Or do I not have a meaningful concept of their relative speeds?

Comment: @JohnDouma It's not a stationary observer. When you move your frame of reference you can make things appear superluminal. https://arstechnica.com/science/2018/09/behind-the-headlines-why-things-look-like-theyre-moving-faster-than-light/

Comment: @it'sahirecarbaby That's classical relativity. One of the postulates of special relativity is that the speed of light in a given medium is the same for all observers moving relative to each other in an inertial reference frame. That means that if you are driving at $0.9c$ and you turn your headlights on, you will measure the speed of light coming from your headlights as the same speed as someone who is parked.

Comment: @JohnDouma I'm already fully aware nothing is able to perceive something moving at greater than light speed relative to itself.  But if I perceive two things in opposing directions their relative speed, from my point of view, is $2c$. So the ceiling on speed of two items relative to each other, from a third reference frame is $2c$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faster-than-light

Comment: @it'sahirecarbaby No. That's the point. If you are a massless particle traveling at $c$ and another particle is traveling at you at $c$, you will each perceive the  other as moving at $c$.

Comment: @JohnDouma I don't think you read my comment properly. It specifically disambiguates that I know that, and that is not what I asked, and then it states what I did ask.

Comment: @CyclotomicField where you wrote "you can make things appear superluminal. arstechnica.com/science/2018/09/… " if I understand correctly, you are saying yes, things can appear to be superliminal relative to each other, from the point of view of a third observer, correct?

Comment: @it'sahirecarbaby [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/107352/breaking-the-speed-of-light-relative-to-a-moving-object) may have what you need. Look at DJohnM's answer. He makes your point but then goes further. I agree. This is a good question.

Comment: @JohnDouma yeah, as you say I see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/107359/122325 giving an interpretation of superluminal speeds so I'm asking the question using THAT interpretation of $\sqrt2 \cdot c$.  I'll add that to the question.

Comment: I'm glad that is settled out, but I am unsure of your question here. Do you mean that is the maximum count of objects that could be travelling such that from your perspective, every pair of them are approaching each other at $\sqrt 2 c$? Because it is from your perspective only, Relativity doesn't come into this, other than limiting their approach to you to $c$. It is basically a Newtonian problem. I believe the answer to that is $4$, arranged at the vertices of a tetrahedron.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I can't reconcile your "relativity doesn't come into it" with my "Newtonian answer is three because three is the max number of bodies which can travel orthogonally, i.e. such that the limit of their speeds relative to each other is $\sqrt2 v$ as their speeds $v$ approache infinity.

Comment: Tell you what - why don't you try answering my question first, then I can address yours. Until you address my question, I cannot be sure I know what you are talking about. But on general principles, relativity is about how the observations of different observers relate to each other. But you are describing the observations of a single observer only, so there is no relativity going on.

Comment: Sorry @PaulSinclair yes, I mean exactly what you wrote in your first sentence of this comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4720090/how-many-objects-can-i-perceive-to-all-be-travelling-at-speed-arbitrarily-close?noredirect=1#comment10000764_4720090 .  Because your second statement takes an affirmative answer to your question as a premise, I would not otherwise have proceeded to discuss your second statement, had hte answer not been "yes". But I apologise, I should have answered that for the total avoidance of doubt.

Comment: Well, as I said, becaue you are just looking at the situation from a single observer (really, a single observation), it is automatically Newtonian, My belief (not proved) that the answer is 4 comes from assuming that all pairs add up to the same approach velocity because the entire situation is symmetric: any two particles have the same relation with each other as any other two particles. In particular, the particles would all have to be equidistant to each other - i.e., at the vertices of a tetrahedron with the observer at the center, and all particles heading directly towards them.

Comment: @PaulSinclair in $\Bbb R^3$ if we pick three **edges** of the tetrahedron as the paths then all three are orthogonal, the limit of their velocities *relative to each other* is $\sqrt2\cdot v$ as their individual velocities approach $v$. But my view at the moment is that we cannot get four close to that relative speed in a Newtonian $\Bbb R^3$ world because four geodesics cannot be orthogonal on that manifold. The question however probes at whether the space in which relativity is situated, agrees.

Comment: The edges of a regular tetrahedron are not orthogonal. The faces are equilateral triangles, so the angle between any two edges is $60^\circ$. The angle between the trajectory of the particles (towards the center) and the lines between them (edges) is $\sin^{-1}\frac 1{\sqrt 3}$. If 2 of the particles are travelling at $v$ towards the center, the rate of shrinkage of the edge is $\frac 4{\sqrt 3}v$, Setting that to $\sqrt2 c$ gives $v =\frac{\sqrt 6}4 c$, which is possible. So yes, you can have four particles mutually approaching each other at $\sqrt 2 c$ as seen from a single observer.

Comment: @PaulSinclair sorry for the ambiguity I meant three orthogonal edges of a non-regular tetraheadron. Is your example not exceeding the light speed barrier?

Comment: I described the tetrahedron as being symmetric with respect to each of the particles at the vertices. A non-regular tetrahedron does not have this property. $\frac{\sqrt 6}4c < c$. The particles are all traveling straight towards the observer in the center, and that is the velocity the observer sees them as travelling. The observer does not see anything travelling faster than light. They only calculate that the the particles should be approaching each other faster than light from the observer's perspective.

Comment: ok @PaulSinclair I get you so it could look like up to four, assuming the observer naively calculates their relative velocities

Comment: That "naively calculates" is exactly the calculation method your whole question is about.  I've shown that 4 is possible. I doubt more than 4 can be done while maintaining the requirement that any two particles must approach each other at the same speed. You certainly cannot get more than 4 that are all equidistant from each other., but speed and distance are different things.